# Why do both map (^2) xs and map (2^) xs work as expected in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Why does

```
map (^2) [1..10]
```

work and also

```
map (2^) [1..10]
```

work?

I'd expect it only to work with one of them, not for both.

I thought map would iterate over all the elements of `[1..10]` and then do

```
[1^2, 2^2, 3^2, ...]
```

for `map (^2) [1..10]`. Then I'd expect that when given `map (2^) [1..10]`, it'd yield a sintax error or something, because it'd need the numbers to be after the `^`, not before.

Comment: Why do you expect it to only work for one of them?

Comment: I have to say that I totally didn't understand the question at all either, until luqui answered.  If you just read the [Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/) it's obvious what `(^2)` and `(2^)` mean.  (Then again, I read the entire language spec before using any new programming language; I've been told that's an odd habit…)

Comment: That is an odd but awesome habit ephemient so keep it up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Haskell grammar has special support for construct like this, called "operator sections".  If you have any infix operator, like say `#$%`, then the following notation is supported:

```
(#$%)   = \x y -> x #$% y
(#$% y) = \x   -> x #$% y
(x #$%) = \y   -> x #$% y
```

So you are expecting some mathematical consistency to break this, and if Haskell were a miniscule language like Forth, I would be inclined to agree with your intuition. The reason it works is basically "because they wrote it to work like that".

*(It was added also to reduce ambiguity - does `f + x` mean `f` applied to two arguments, or does it mean `+` applied to two arguments? Since it actually means the latter, how do we represent the former? Answer: using `()` to introduce an operator section.)*

Comment: Ah! "The reason it works is basically "because they wrote it to work like that"". that was what it looked like! luqui to the rescue, as always! thanks

Comment: Well described at [Haskell Report > Expressions > Sections](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-300003.5)

Answer (score 3):

Haskell knows that `^` is an infix operator so it interprets (in mathematical notation) `(2^)` as `f(x) = 2^x` and `(^2)` as `f(x) = x^2`.

Answer (score 0):

(2 ^) creates a new function that takes a parameter and invocates (2 ^ parameter). It is a way of curryfication.

Here's a link with the theory behind it: [Partial Application(Haskell.org)](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application)

Comment: that is not quite what i asked for in the original post ( i guess i wasnt very explicit). look at the other answers. thanks anyway

Comment: i see that... sorry for not understanding the question.